# subtracting values from a matrix when an object collides with another

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, pygame

Right now, I have a class that creates a grid, aligns an object to a grid, and then as the object moves over the grid, it counts the number of times the object overlaps with a specific cell.

My goal is to, instead of counting the number of overlaps, subtract the number of overlaps from an N-value. For example, instead of ending the program when a value in the hitGrid is 10, the program will subtract from 10 and end when hitGrid is 0.

Here is my code:

```py
WIDTH, HEIGHT, MARGIN = 10, 10, 1
Object = [[1]]

class GridObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, grid, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)

        # create image from grid
        self.grid = grid
        self.gridsize = (len(grid[0]), len(grid))
        imgsize = self.gridsize[0] * (WIDTH+MARGIN), self.gridsize[1] * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)
        self.image = pg.Surface(imgsize, flags = pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        col = BLACK
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                if self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * c + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * r + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                    pg.draw.rect(self.image, col, rect)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(8, 0).rotate(randrange(360))
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self, boundrect, hitGrid, hitList):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.rect.left <= boundrect.left or self.rect.right >= boundrect.right:
            self.vel.x *= -1                            
        if self.rect.top <= boundrect.top or self.rect.bottom >= boundrect.bottom:
            self.vel.y *= -1     

        # align rect to grid
        gridpos = round(self.rect.x / (WIDTH+MARGIN)), round(self.rect.y / (HEIGHT+MARGIN))
        self.rect.topleft = gridpos[0] * (WIDTH+MARGIN), gridpos[1] * (HEIGHT+MARGIN)

        # increment touched filled
        global max_hit
        max_hit = 0
        
        oldHitList = hitList[:]
        hitList.clear()
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                p = gridpos[1] + r, gridpos[0] + c                
                if p in oldHitList:
                    hitList.append(p)
                elif self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    if p[0] < len(hitGrid) and p[1] < len(hitGrid[p[0]]):
                        hitList.append(p)
                        if p not in oldHitList:
                            hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]] +=1
                            max_hit = max(max_hit, hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]])
                            print(hitGrid[p[0]][p[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't totally clear what your intent is here because the code above is incomplete in a few areas...  That said, there are a couple strategies you should think about.  And the block where you are trying to compute this now is on track for "ugly code block of the year" award, so we need to do *something*.

A couple things to think about...

1. How do you want to handle the case where the object remains in the same grid square for multiple time steps?  Perhaps you need to keep track of the "last grid square" and only do an update when there is a change...

in pseudo-code...

```
old_gridpos = None  <- set at start of game

# compute new pos in update()
if current_gridpos != old_gridpos:
    check for grid square usage (see below)
    old_gridpos = current_gridpos
```

2. I see you have a 2-dimensional angular vector for velocity...  What if the object moves fast enough diagonally or in any direction and "skips over" a corner of a square?  (This gets tough.)
3. Your tracking system now appears to be a list of grids hit.  That is tough to work with computationally.  You should flip this around and use a 2-d index and keep count for each point.  Wayyy easier.  You could use a `dictionary`, 2-d list, or `numpy` array.  Any of them will be fast enough for a simple game, so use whatever you are comfortable with.  This tracking data structure should be a property of the game and initialized at start, etc.  Here is a thumbnail sketch of how you might do this with a dictionary, which is probably easiest.

```
In [12]: grid_count = {}                                                        

In [13]: max_hits = 3                                                           

In [14]: def check_max_hits(position): 
    ...:     grid_count[position] = grid_count.get(position, 0) + 1 
    ...:     if grid_count[position] >= max_hits: 
    ...:         return True 
    ...:     return False 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                        

In [15]: check_max_hits((1,2))                                                  
Out[15]: False

In [16]: check_max_hits((2,4))                                                  
Out[16]: False

In [17]: check_max_hits((1,2))                                                  
Out[17]: False

In [18]: grid_count                                                             
Out[18]: {(1, 2): 2, (2, 4): 1}

In [19]: check_max_hits((1,2))                                                  
Out[19]: True
```

You could make a similar function and call it from your `update` function after you have computed `gridpos`

Comment: Can you give an example with Numpy? I would like to see what that would look like. That seems interesting